# How to clear the search field of twitter typeahead.js after performing a search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, typeahead.js

I have written a search functionality using typeahead.js. After I perform a search using the input text box, the search query remains in the search box without being cleared. The code is shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'countries',
                remote: 'localhost:8080/countrySearch?key=%QUERY'
            }).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
                window.location.replace(`localhost:8081/#/country?name=${datum.value}`);
            }).typeahead('val', myVal)
              .typeahead('setQuery', '')
        });
```

Please help me with clearing the search box